# Type of visa for job interview in China

Tags: visas, china, work

I'm planning to go for a job interview to Beijing. It's for a subsidiary of a US company. I'm wondering what kind of visa I should apply for. It's not really a business trip but obviously it doesn't count as tourism either.

Comment: Better go on tourist.

Answer (score 1):

My local Chinese consulate lists the following types of visas that could possibly apply to you:

- F - Issued to those who intend to go to China for exchanges, visits, study tours and other activities.
- L - Issued to those who intend to go to China as a tourist.
- M - Issued to those who intend to go to China for commercial and trade activities.
- R - Issued to those who are high-level talents or whose skills are urgently needed in China.
- Z - Issued to those who intend to work in China.

You can eliminate L, probably R, and Z at this time. So you would probably be issued an F or M visa.

In practice, you don't specifically choose which one applies to you. You tick the box on the visa application form which applies best to you, and the consulate will then decide which visa type to issue. The choices may look something like this:

- `[]` 旅游 Tourism
- `[]` 交流、考察、访问 Non-business visit
- `[]` 商业贸易 Business & Trade
- ...
- `[]` 其他(请说明) Other (Please specify)：

If you are unsure, describe your intended purpose of visit (job interview with a company) in the "Other" field. If you select one of the other options (such as "Non-business visit"), there is another space later on the application form to provide additional information about your application.

If you can get an invitation letter from the company who will be interviewing you, that will probably help a lot and you should submit that letter with your visa application. If the company has interviewed and employed non-Chinese nationals previously, this procedure will be familiar to them.